# Can you help me understand Taylor's Theorem in the form used in the Numerical Optimization book?

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion

Nocedal and Wright in their book Numerical Optimization give Taylor's Theorem in the following form:

> Suppose $f:\mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R$ is continuously differentiable and that $p \in \mathbf R^n$. Then we have that $$f(x+p)=f(x)+\nabla f(x+tp)^Tp,$$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.
>
> Moreover, if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, we have that $$\nabla f(x+p)=\nabla f(x)+\int^1_0 \nabla^2f(x+tp)p  dt,$$
>
> and that $$f(x+p)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^Tp +\frac 1 2 p^T \nabla^2f(x+tp)p,$$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.

This form is different from the usual form i see, e.g. from
$$f(x+p)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^Tp+\frac 1 2 p^T\nabla^2f(x)p+O(?).$$

Can you relate these two forms? E.g. how can you obtain one from other? 1st and 3rd equations  seem to correspond to first and second order usual expansion, but the 2nd is totally new? Can you interpret them?

I am at the beginning of the book, and the authors tell understanding these equations is important.

Comment: What you have quoted are the zeroth-order and the first-order Taylor series with remainder. Then what you said you are familiar with is a second-order Taylor series, without the remainder term being written explicitly. Maybe you are not used to having the remainder term being written explicitly.

Comment: Yes, the first and last expressions are the Taylor series of the one-variable function $t \mapsto f(x+tp)$ with Lagrange's form of the remainder. The middle one is essentially (if taken componentwise) Taylor's theorem with the integral form of the remainder.